# Select rows and group by value without other columns in aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I try to get some rows from a table where I group by one value but the other columns I want to get back are not in the `group by` or any aggregate clause. It works fine on `sqlite` but does not work on `postgresql`.

| value1 | created | value2 | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 10 | foo |
| 5 | 2022-03-01 | 4 | foo |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 6 | bar |
| 7 | 2022-02-01 | 3 | bar |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 | 20 | bar |

I would all rows grouped by `name` where `created` is max for that `name`. E.g:

| MAX(value1) | created | value2 | SUM(value) | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-03-01 | 4 | 14 | foo |
| 7 | 2022-04-01 | 20 | 29 | bar |

The problem is that I cannot use `MAX` in a where clause, nor can I just group by `name` as SQL complains that I need to group by `value2` as well, which I don't want. I want just the value from the row with the max `value1` grouped by `name`.

Or in other words: I want one row per `name`, which is selected based on the max `value1` with an additional column that is the sum of all `value2` for that `name`.

The closest I got is:

```sql
SELECT MAX(value1), created, value2, SUM(value2), name
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

But obviously that does not work. Any help is welcome!

Comment: You could use CTE's as one solution.

Comment: @secana Still need to fix your `value2` in your update, should be 3 not 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a couple options here but you can do this with a CTE like the following:

```
WITH agg_data AS
(
SELECT name
     , MAX(value1) maxval1
     , SUM(value2) sumval2
  FROM t
 GROUP BY name
)
SELECT ad.*
     , t2.created
     , t2.value2
  FROM agg_data ad
  JOIN t t2 ON t2.value1 = ad.maxval1 AND t2.name = ad.name
;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a29cdcdb130da93babd6dbbac47a187d) is a DBFiddle to show a working example.

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by created desc) rn
    from T
)
select max(created) as created, max(value2) filter (where rn = 1) as value2, name
from data
group by name;
```

You could also use this inside the CTE:

```
first_value(value2) over (partition by name order by created desc) as value2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT m.maxvalue1, t.created, t.value2, m.sumvalue2, t.name
FROM table t
inner join
(
   SELECT MAX(value1) as maxvalue1, SUM(value2) as sumvalue2, name
   FROM table
   GROUP BY name
) m
on m.value1 = t.value1 and m.name = t.name
```